# How do you score points in this game?

Tags: waiting-in-line-3d

I have played this game a few times, and it's not clear what you need to do to score points.  So, far all I've managed to do is to stay awake for 2 minutes or so, and then punch myself into oblivion.

I assume based upon the controls, that there will be some movement in the line at some point?

Or is this just a big sociological experiment to see if people will play a game without knowing why?

Comment: In an interview on CBC's As it Happens the developer said there was a way to score points though he did not say how. http://www.cbc.ca/asithappens/features/2013/11/28/waiting-in-line-may-be-worlds-most-boring-video-game/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that the string "scored 0 points" is hard-coded in the game, I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you cannot score any points in this game.

> name: 'I just waited ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' and
>   scored 0 points!',

Comment: Related http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/2013/11/28/waiting-in-line-3d_n_4354578.html

Answer (score 6):

The game may have been updated since Jason posted his answer, since the score isn't hardcoded in the message anymore:

```
name: 'I just waited ' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' and scored ' + 
      ( score || 0 ) + ' points!',
```

However, it still seems rigged not to allow you to score any points. The only place `score` is assigned a value is here:

```
// Increase score!
score += ~~( Math.atan2( delta, Math.pow( delta, 2 ) ) );
```

The expression `~~( Math.atan2( delta, Math.pow( delta, 2 ) ) )` will always be 0 since `delta` is an integer, and `score` is never initialized to a numerical value so it always has the value `NaN`.

To top it all off, if you do fiddle with the code to give `score` an actual value, the game will crash here because `images.hud_fill` is undefined:

```
if ( score > 0 ) {
   ctx.drawImage( images.hud_fill, 902, 678, 122, 396 );
   drawFont( score, 678, 902 );
}
```

Comment: `delta = now - last_render_time` and `last_render_time = Date.now()`. delta is the number of miliseconds between when `now` is defined and when last_render_time is defined. So i don't think it's 0.

Comment: @char1es Plug any number into `~~( Math.atan2( delta, Math.pow( delta, 2 ) ) )` and the result you will get is zero. http://jsfiddle.net/Nq4Hb/6/

Comment: `~~(Math.atan2( 0.5, Math.pow( 0.5, 2 ) ) ) == 1` :)

Comment: Ahh yes thanks for clarifying, i didn't see the floor operator. However, if we were to remove the floor and replace it with `100*` this would give us a number of some kind

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Good point. :) But in this case, `delta` is an integer and so the result will always be 0.

Comment: @char1es Yes, and if I multiplied my bank balance by 100, I'd be a millionaire, but that's not the reality. :)

Comment: haha, yes well im simply trying to figure out a way to actually generate a feasible score ;D